# Add a hashtag (#) to beginning of each word in a HTML 5 form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hashtag

I have a form on a page on my HTML document and I was wondering if there is a way in javascript or jquery to add a hashtag (#) to the start of each word (there might be more than one word entered)

Comment: Which words, in a form field? In your document, what did you try?

Comment: On page load or when the user is typing?

Comment: A hashtag is a whole word prefixed with a `#`. `#` is a pound/number sign.

Comment: I would like the words IN the form to have the # added before them while the user is typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a keyup event Listener and some replace and indexOf:

```
<input id="test">

<script>
var a = document.getElementById('test');
a.addEventListener('keyup',addthis);

function addthis() {
    b = a.value.replace('#',''); 
    a.value = '#'+b

    if (a.value.indexOf(' '))
    {
    a.value = a.value.replace(' ','#');
    }

}
</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hotfwzcL/)

Comment: baao that works great! Is there anyway to stop it from adding hashtags to spaces?

Comment: @user2640633 try this, it's a little buggy, but kind of works http://jsfiddle.net/hotfwzcL/1/

Comment: Jonathan Lonowski ~ there is a lot of unrelated Jquery that is fixed to this form. I could easily put up the HTML portion of it, but I have a toggle switch that when toggled changes the placeholder text inside the form. I admit that I know very little javascript and jquery....My teacher helps me with most of it and I try to read his code and try to understand it as it goes

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 look at this, this is good to go http://jsfiddle.net/hotfwzcL/2/

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want and moves the cursor to the end of the field to boot.

**Update:** Used `keydown` insteead to filter out multiple spaces.

```
function addHash(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 32 && event.target.value.length) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var elem = event.target,
        val = elem.value;

        if (val.slice(-1) !== '#') {
            elem.value += ' #';
        }
    } else if (!event.target.value.length) {
        if (event.keyCode === 32) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        event.target.value = '#';
    }
}
```

I forked baao's fiddle to test.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/65xm4kgp/7/)**

Comment: Nice one! But if you press space for two times it'll give you extra # too.

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 Please recheck the code. It now adds # to the beginning as well, and does everything you want. Holding down space doesn't break it either (it does break baao's: try holding down space in his code). If you want to remove the spaces, just remove the space below `#` in `elem.value += ' #';`.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with the jquery onchange eventlistner.

the script below gets the value of the inputfield and splits each word on a space " " which makes it an array. then it loops trough the array of words and if the word does not have a "#" at the beginning of the word it adds one. then it replaces the old value from the input field with the new one.

```
$('#input').on('change', function(e){
    var input_string = $(this).val();
    var words = input_string.split(" ");
    var output = "";
    console.log(words);
    $.each(words , function(i, word ){
        console.log(word);
        if(word.substr(0, 1) == "#") 
        {            
            output += word + " ";           
        }
        else
        {
           output += "#" +  word + " ";    
        }
         console.log(output);
    });

    $(this).val(output);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dgs9kapc/6/

Comment: Makaze that works great except it doesnt add a # to the first word! Thanks for all the help!!!!

Comment: I fortgot to asign a value to output. Thats why the first word did not get a #. I updated the fiddle and the link.